# How to use Amazon Lex to capture user's random string input

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I need to accept a user input that can be any string, but Lex does not support AMAZON.Literal type. I've seen other articles talking about using intent_request, but I am not able to make it work.

In my setting, I have only one utterance: {string}.
I also defined "string" as a slot using AlphaNumeric type, with "Required" unchecked. (Should I even use AlphaNumeric?)

In my Initialization and Validation Lambda function, I have this:

```
def delegate(session_attributes, slots):
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Delegate',
            'slots': slots
        }
    }

def perform_action(intent_request):
    source = intent_request['invocationSource']
    slots = intent_request['currentIntent']['slots']
    if source == 'DialogCodeHook':
        slots['string'] = intent_request['inputTranscript']
        return delegate({}, slots)

def dispatch(intent_request):
    return perform_action(intent_request)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return dispatch(event)
```

If I enter something like "abc", it's ok (since it's pure AlphaNumeric). But if I enter something like "what is this", then it always returns "Sorry, can you please repeat that?". It seems, even with the Lambda function, the slot type "AlphaNumeric" is still there to doing its job. I've tried a few other types but nothing worked.

What am I missing here? How do I make it to accept any random string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Till now doesn't support for capturing the random string.
- But you can use Amazon.organization for capturing the random string
- Else you need to write the custom code like if it goes to the Fallback intent we need to check the previous state. if previous state is your slot then fill the slot value with the user statement

Comment: Do you have an example of how the custom code should look like?